# is SETNX truly atomic?

Tags: redis

Redis has [SETNX](https://redis.io/commands/setnx) command.

I read the documentation. However, it doesn't explicitly says whether it's atomic or not.

I read that it's not recommended to be used for distributed locks. However, my case is a little bit simpler. All I need to make sure that whomever comes first (first caller) set the value and second caller receives an error (SETNX will return 0).

So, the question is, is it truly atomic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `SETNX` is atomic and will do what you ask regardless of how many callers there are.

Individual Redis commands are essentially always atomic, since Redis is single-threaded. So the documentation doesn't bother to specify that for every single command. (Perhaps the most direct reference comes from the first line of the [FAQ](https://redis.io/topics/faq): "Redis is a different evolution path in the key-value DBs where values can contain more complex data types, with atomic operations defined on those data types.")

When it comes to setting and releasing locks you're no longer dealing with a single command, so that's why there are other considerations. But the `SETNX` command itself is atomic.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform atomic operations you can use [`MULTI`](https://redis.io/commands/multi) and [`EXEC`](https://redis.io/commands/exec) to group commands into a transaction, at which point all commands will be atomic.
You can read more on their website: https://redis.io/topics/transactions

Make sure you read the whole document because there are some important notes about failures.

> It's important to note that **even when a command fails, all the other commands in the queue are processed** – Redis will *not* stop the processing of commands.

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question ;)